# How to mask the inside of an element with snap.svg or svg

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I would like to know if it is possible to mask part of an element
with the shape of another element. It sounds a bit abstract like this so I invite you to have a look at the example:

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/mdcrwoxt/) of what I would like to do.

Example html (just a visual example):

```
<div id="tomask"></div>
<div id="mask"></div>
<p>I want the darker part to be transparent</p>
```

Example css (same):

```
#tomask{
margin:50px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:black;
opacity:0.3;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}

#mask{
margin:60px;
width:80px;
height:80px;
background:black;
opacity:0.3;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

Comment: If this is SVG, just create a rect with a stroke and no fill and place it last ? I'm assuming I'm not really understanding what you are after.

Comment: Imagine I want to make a red square with a round hole in it's center, how do I do that with stroke?

Comment: like this... https://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/tx9snm74/2/ ?

Comment: yes, exactly like this. I don't know how you've done it but i'll study your code to be sure I get it right, thanks!